# css how to specify style for a class that is a child to another element with the same class name

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

May not be the best wording for my question, here's what I'm trying to accomplish.

I'm using `Angular2` app with `bootstrap 3` styling, where we are using many components (directives in angular1.x). This also leads to us having components inside components.

On one of my pages, I have the bootstrap class `.well`, and then there's another component inside that one that also utilizes `.well`. So if you're familiar with bootstrap, a `.well` inside another `.well` yields quite a bit of padding.

So, I want to write a css selector where I remove the padding for the inner `.well` when it's inside another `.well`.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
.well .well {
  padding: 0;
}

div#doubled-up-well .well {
  padding: 0;
}

div.well .well {
  padding: 0;
}

div.well form.well {
  padding: 0;
}
```

None of these seem to work, what am I doing wrong here?

Here's how it's structured to give a better idea:

```
<div class="well" id="doubled-up-well">
  <my-custom-component>
    <form class="well {some more angular classes here}"></form>
  </my-custom-component>
</div>
```

Does it have to do with there being more classes defined on my `form` element? Is it because there's an element in between my `div` and my `form` (which is why I DIDN'T use the > in my CSS selector)?

Edit: I've also tried these:

```
div#doubled-up-well > member-add-member-demo > form.well.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-valid {
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: red !important;
}

div#doubled-up-well form.well.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-valid {
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Edit: Here's the fiddle with the exact html that is rendered on the page. FYI - the fiddle WORKS, it's only not working in my actual app.

https://jsfiddle.net/rv69f6ok/2/

Comment: Try inpecting the element and copy the exact used classes

Comment: perhaps a problem with the specificity: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity. For a quick test you can use `padding: 0 !important;`.

Comment: Try .well .well {padding: 0 !important;}

Comment: Is there a way I can do this WITHOUT specifying all of those angular classes that are inserted when rendering the page? That's what I'm trying to avoid...

Comment: @SebastianBrosch that didn't work either...Is there also a way to figure out why a particular css definition is NOT getting picked up?

Comment: Did you try giving `my-custom-component` a class and doing a selector based on that or perhaps `my-custom-component .well` as a selector itself?

Comment: @ArjanKnol that didn't work....

Comment: What is your custom component? What HTML is it generating?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto that's how the elements look when rendered on the page. So that IS the html that it's generating

Comment: have you tried with another rule (unset yet like color or outline or bg or whatever ...) to check that your selector/html are a match? style loaded ? html that validates, brackets missing or another typo, ... my-custom-component might have style or collapsing margins confusing you ...

Comment: You can use a negative margin. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/

Comment: All of them work well, so what is different from [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rv69f6ok/) in your scenario?

Comment: @Marvin I updated your fiddle (thanks for posting by the way), with the actual values on my page. Of course, it works just fine in the fiddle, like you said: https://jsfiddle.net/rv69f6ok/2/ This is just a straight copy from the parent div with ALL of it's contents.

Comment: you try to change the padding of inner `.wel`l or the outer one?

Comment: @DanielH just the inner well

Comment: @ganders could you just post the rendered HTML (inspect the code from your browser)? because we can't reproduce your problem for the code you have right now example: https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/9p3t0sgy/

Comment: @DanielH i pasted a link to the jsfiddle that has exactly that in my comment above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into this issue as well, and in my case it was because I had to write the styles in the specific component in which they need to be modified.  If I tried to write .well .well in a global css or in the css of the parent component, it wouldn't work because the styles for each component are isolated to that specific component.

So in your case, I'd write a style for .well in the component that's the child, where you want to get rid of the padding.  If you're using that component in other areas where you don't want that reduced padding to apply, I'd probably add some class to the same element where the child .well class is included.  That extra class can serve as a flag that will have its own reduced padding value, and will overwrite the .well class your css by adding specificity like .foo.well { padding: 0; }

Comment: You're right, this one component is used on another page that does NOT have the parent well. Which is why I only want to remove the extra padding when the wells are doubled-up. By the way, my css specification is only in the css file for this particular component, NOT on the parent css or global css.

Comment: in that case, I'd probably add an @input as a flag as to whether or not you should kill the padding.  skinny="true" in the HTML, then in the component, have @Input() skinny: boolean;  and then you apply an ngStyle or ngClass based on the value of that input.

Comment: interesting, I'll try that!

Comment: Thanks David, taking this approach, and then doing a [ngClass]="{'className': isWellDoubledUp()}" worked perfect